# SWT ScrolledComposite Hand Tool: Scroll Proportional To Mouse Movement

Tags: java, swt

I would like to implement a "hand tool" with which the user can scroll/move something with the mouse. This feature is known from various programs such as [Gimp](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-move.html). If the user presses the left mouse button, the tool should be activated. If the mouse is now moved, the underlying object should also be moved - **proportional** to the mouse movement. Hence, if the user presses the mouse and moves it by e.g. 10px, the underlying object should also be moved by 10px. I thought that it should work with my code below, but it does not work properly. The movement of the underlying [`ScrolledComposite`](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/custom/ScrolledComposite.html) is too fast.

The code below is ready-to-run, so you can directly play with it.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.ScrolledComposite;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MouseMoveListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class HandTool {

  public static boolean moveGraphActive = false;
  public static Point moveStartPos = new Point(0, 0);
  public static ScrolledComposite sc;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);

    Text text = new Text(sc, SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    String multiLineText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      multiLineText += "Hello World SWT " + i + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    text.setText(multiLineText);
    text.setEnabled(false);
    text.pack();
    sc.setContent(text);

    sc.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void mouseDown(final MouseEvent e) {
        moveGraphActive = e.button == 1;
        if (moveGraphActive) {
          moveStartPos.x = e.x;
          moveStartPos.y = e.y;
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e) {
        moveGraphActive = false;
      }
    });

    sc.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener() {
      @Override
      public void mouseMove(final MouseEvent e) {
        if (moveGraphActive) {
          // FIXME the movement of the canvas should be proportional
          // to the mouse
          // movement
          final int newX = sc.getOrigin().x + moveStartPos.x - e.x;
          final int newY = sc.getOrigin().y + moveStartPos.y - e.y;
          sc.setOrigin(newX, newY);
        }
      }
    });

    shell.setSize(500, 150);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right, there is just a small mistake.

```
final int newX = sc.getOrigin().x + moveStartPos.x - e.x;
final int newY = sc.getOrigin().y + moveStartPos.y - e.y;
```

should be

```
final int newX = startOrigin.x + moveStartPos.x - e.x;
final int newY = startOrigin.y + moveStartPos.y - e.y;
```

where `startOrigin` is the origin of the `ScrolledComposite` when you started dragging. I've updated your code:

```
private static boolean           moveGraphActive = false;
private static Point             moveStartPos    = new Point(0, 0);
private static ScrolledComposite sc;
private static Point             startOrigin;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    sc = new ScrolledComposite(shell, SWT.V_SCROLL);

    Text text = new Text(sc, SWT.MULTI | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    String multiLineText = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        multiLineText += "Hello World SWT " + i + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    text.setText(multiLineText);
    text.setEnabled(false);
    text.pack();
    sc.setContent(text);

    sc.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseDown(final MouseEvent e)
        {
            moveGraphActive = e.button == 1;
            if (moveGraphActive)
            {
                moveStartPos.x = e.x;
                moveStartPos.y = e.y;
                startOrigin = sc.getOrigin();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseUp(final MouseEvent e)
        {
            moveGraphActive = false;
            startOrigin = null;
        }
    });

    sc.addMouseMoveListener(new MouseMoveListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void mouseMove(final MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (moveGraphActive)
            {
                // FIXED
                final int newX = startOrigin.x + moveStartPos.x - e.x;
                final int newY = startOrigin.y + moveStartPos.y - e.y;
                sc.setOrigin(newX, newY);
            }
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(500, 150);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```